# Game World View Bounds

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, coordinates, scene2d

So I have two stages in my game. One for my game world and another for UI stuff (like touch-pad controls and a sidebar). The design I am trying to achieve is right below.

[image: Image of panning game area on left and UI stuff on right.]

I have managed to render the side rectangle on the right part of the screen pretty well, but the problem is the game is centered in the center of the screen and not centered in the game area.

I tried setting the bounds and culling area on the root group of the `WorldStage`, but it sets the bounds in game coordinates when I want a fixed rectangle around the game area.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use [viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)? Not really into libgdx..

Comment: Yea viewports did the trick, but the only problem is I use Tiled and the map gets stretched out to the viewport of the UI stage, even though I applied the camera of the game stage.